# How can I use jquery validate to prevent navigation via menu links (if form invalid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="www.wherever.com/page2">

<div class="question">
 <label for="q1">What is your name?</label>
 <input id="q1" name="q1" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Continue" />

</form>
```

Which is validated by jquery validate plugin:

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var VALIDATE = {};

    VALIDATE.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            $("#myform").validate({
                rules: {
                    q1: {required: true},                           
                    },

                messages: {
                    q1:     {
                        required: "Answer the question",
                            },  

                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    $(D).ready(function($) {
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if (element.hasClass("errorleft")) {
                       error.insertBefore(element);
                    }else{error.insertAfter(element);}
                }
            });


        VALIDATE.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I also have a side bar menu that allows users to jump around within the form (it's a multi page form, each page has a link in this menu

```
<div id="leftmenu" class="leftmenu">
<ul id="sidebarmenu1">
<li><a href="?page=introduction">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=introduction-2">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=survey-2">I: Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The form validates just fine if the user exits the page via the submit / continue button at the bottom of the page, but I want the form to also validate when they attempt to leave a page by clicking on these menu links.

What I've tried so far:
I've added this script such that the clicks within the menu count as form submissions:

```
$('#leftmenu').click(function() {  
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

And I can see the validation errors work when these clicks happen, but the browser still leaves the page - unlike when the form is submitted via the continue button.

How can I adjust this so that jquery validator prevents these links working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the default action of the anchor tags..

The form gets submitted but because of the default behavior  it gets redirected to a differnt page..

Instead of adding a click event to the `#leftmenu`, add it to the anchors and also make sure you stop the default action..

```
$('#leftmenu a').on('click',function(e) {

    // Prevents the default action of
    // redirecting to the page specified.
    e.preventDefault();
    // Submit the form which will validate
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - this works, and thanks for explaining it in a way that helps me learn more :)